# Make permanent changes in PHP-FPM's settings

Tags: php-fpm, server-settings

I'm using php-fpm (php 8.2 and 8.3) under Ubuntu 22.4. I want to permanently increase the allowed max size of uploads.

I therefore didn't want to edit the php.ini, which will be reinitialized when updating php. I came up with adding an extra conf file in pool.d/extra.conf with

```
[www]
php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize] = 32M
```

Which indeed modifies the setting, but then just realised it wouldn't probably make it through an update.
So I tried to add

```
php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize] = 32M
```

in the override.conf of php-fpm (sudo systemctl edit php8.2-fpm.service), but it just doesn't work.

How can I make permanent a change of php server settings under ubuntu?

Comment: On Debian-based systems, the modified config files aren't 'reinitialized' when updating packages by default, unless `apt` is specifically instructed to overwrite the configurations. Review your updating procedures.